# Moving Data to Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I've got an *Amazon EC2* instance running and I'm trying to move files from another web server to the *EC2*.

I'm using **wget** on the *EC2* to fetch and **30GB Zip file**. It's running at 100KB/s to 150KB/s on the EC2. It's expected to finish in 2 days 10 hours.

Is there a faster way to upload files of this size to EC2? Does Amazon have a Server that would make this easier?

I Googled this one and went to the Amazon's page, all I could fine are tools/services to upload files to S3 and Amazon Snowbowl which I think is too big of a solution of just 30GB.

Thanks!

Comment: Too broad. I can think of multiple technologies to move large amounts of data, Have you considered splitting the file and using multiple parallel transfers? Ever heard of this arcane thing called "ftp"?

Comment: EC2 network speed may go above the speed you mentioned. This can be the source server throttle. Nevertheless, this question scope just to vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used **aria2** to improve the download speed.

```
sudo apt-get install aria2

sudo aria2c -j20 -x16 http://example.com/file.zip
```

This enabled multi-connection download and maximized the available bandwidth. Could have been done with FTP but for us this was a better solution. This was a 30GB zip file from just 1 host/origin running on Apache with `mpm_event`.

Download finished in 8 hours instead of 2d 10h.

Comment: Since EC2 charges is by hours, you may even launch a faster EC2 instance  with higher bandwidth to do this :-D . Then just dump the data into a mounted EBS volume. Choose  your desire instance here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-ec2-config.html

Comment: But I doubt your source apache server able to dump 500MB/s to match m4.10xlarge bandwidth ;-)